# Partial View Search Result returns no results in paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, pagedlist

I have two partial views for search results that is displayed inside the parent view using tab pane of bootstrap.

this is my parent view : (`Index.cshtml` relevant codes only)

```
<form class="form">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {  
        <div class=" form-group">
            @Html.TextBox("search", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, 
                new { @placeholder = "Enter class number", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Search" id="btnclick" />
        </div>
    }
</form> 
<div class="tab-content col-xs-12">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="info">
        @if (Model.student_info.Count() != 0)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_studentinfo")
        }
        else
        {
            <h4 style="padding:5px;">No records found.</h4>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="grades">
        @if (Model.gradeperterm.Count() != 0)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_gradeterm")
        }
        else
        {
            <h4 style="padding:5px;">No records found.</h4>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Then for each of my partial view I put the pagedlistpager

```
@if (Model.student_info.Count > 1)
{ 
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.student_info, 
        page =>Url.Action("Index", 
            new { page = Page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter}))
}
```

Then my controller looks like this:

```
Guid query = new Guid();
query = (from b in db.school 
         where b.class_nr == search 
         select b.class_id).FirstOrDefault();

if (search != null)
{
    page = 1;
}
else 
{
    search = currentfilter;
}

ViewBag.CurrentFilter = search;

int pageSize = 5;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
var smodel = new schoolmodel
{
    student_info = db.student_info.Where(x => x.class_id == query)
        .OrderBy(x => x.recorded_at_date_time)
        .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize),

    gradeperterm = db.gradeperterm.Where(x => x.class_id == query)
         .OrderBy(x => x.term)
         .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
};

return View(patmodel);
```

When I search, it displays the first five pages for each tab-pane successfully however, when I click on the next page it displays the "No results found" but my search string and current filter are not null as shown in my url. How can I make it work ? I am totally new to mvc. Answers would be much appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Partial views are meant to be like fragments of Razor so You need to pass the data for the partial views using as shown below

`@Html.Partial("_studentinfo",Model)`

Or Alternatively, If you need to do some amount of pre-processing, you could use a Child Action so that it can have its own Controller Action as shown

`@Html.Action("controller","action",new { id = 1, otherRouteParam = "pagekey" })`

and let that action render the partial view after said pre-processing

```
public PartialViewResult Action(int id, string otherRouteParam){
   //Additional Processing like Get a PagedList Slice of Data
   return PartialView("_studentinfo", result);
}
```

Comment: I tried @Html.Partial("_studentinfo",Model) but I still get the same result.